# Show that acceleration is always perpendicular to the radius vector

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vectors

I need a little help on this problem:

"A particle moves with radius vector $\vec r(t)=acos(\theta)\hat i +asin(\theta)\hat j+bcosh(\omega t)\hat k$ where $\omega$ is a constant and $\theta$ is a function of $t$: $\theta\equiv \theta (t)$.

(a) Find the velocity $\dot r=\frac {d\vec r}{dt}$ at any time $t$

(b) Find the acceleration $\ddot r=\frac {d^2\vec r}{dt^2}$

(c) Show that the acceleration $\ddot r$ is always perpendicular to the radius vector $\vec r$ when $\theta =\pm \frac{b\omega}{a}cosh(\omega t)$

**This is what I've done so far:**

(a)

$\dot r=\frac{d}{dt}(acos\theta \hat i +asin\theta \hat j +bcosh(\omega t)\hat k)$

$\dot r =\frac{d}{d\theta }(acos\theta \hat i +asin\theta \hat j +bcosh(\omega t)\hat k)\frac {d\theta }{dt}$

$\dot r =(-asin\theta \hat i +acos\theta \hat j )\dot \theta$

$\dot r =-a\dot \theta sin\theta \hat i +a\dot \theta cos\theta \hat j$

(b)

$\ddot r =\frac {d}{dt}(-a\dot \theta sin\theta \hat i +a\dot \theta cos\theta \hat j)$

$\ddot r =\frac {d}{d\theta }(-a\dot \theta sin\theta \hat i +a\dot \theta cos\theta \hat j)\frac {d\theta }{dt}$

$\ddot r=[(-a\ddot \theta sin\theta -a\dot \theta cos\theta )\hat i+(a\ddot \theta cos\theta-a\dot \theta sin\theta )\hat j]\ddot \theta$

$\ddot r=(-a\ddot \theta ^2sin -a\dot \theta \ddot \theta cos\theta )\hat i +(a\ddot \theta ^2 cos\theta -a\dot \theta \ddot \theta sin\theta )\hat j$

(c)

When $\dot \theta =\pm \frac {b\omega }{a}cosh(\omega t)$, $\ddot r .\vec r=0$

$\ddot r.\vec r=a\ddot \theta cos\theta (-a\ddot \theta sin\theta \pm \frac {b\omega }{a}cosh(\omega t))cos\theta ) +a\ddot \theta sin\theta (a\ddot \theta cos\theta \pm \frac {b\omega }{a}cosh(\omega t))sin\theta )$

$\ddot r.\vec r=-a^2\ddot \theta ^2cos\theta sin\theta \pm a\ddot \theta b\omega cosh(\omega t)cos^2\theta +a^2\ddot \theta ^2cos\theta sin\theta \pm a\ddot \theta b\omega cosh(\omega t)sin^2\theta$

$\ddot r.\vec r=\pm a\ddot \theta b\omega cosh(\omega t)cos^2\theta \pm a\ddot \theta b\omega cosh(\omega t)sin^2\theta $

$\ddot r.\vec r=\pm a\ddot \theta b\omega cosh(\omega t)(cos^2\theta +sin^2\theta )$

$\ddot r.\vec r=\pm a\ddot \theta b\omega cosh(\omega t)$

...

And then I'm stuck! Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you took the first derivative incorrectly.

Note that $\dot{r} = \frac{d}{dt}(a\cos(\theta)\hat{i} + a\sin(\theta)\hat{j} + b\cosh(\omega t) \hat{k})$ must be evaluated component-wise.

In the $\hat{i}$ and $\hat{j}$ component, what you have is correct.  Here, since $\theta$ is a function of $t$, using the chain rule yields the correct answer.

However, in the $\hat{k}$ component, there is no $\theta$ to use the chain rule on!  So, we need to just evaluate the derivative.  We still use the chain rule, but in a much simpler way.  Note that $\frac{d}{dt}(b\cosh(\omega t)) = b\omega \sinh(\omega t)$.

So, our final answer should be $\dot{r} = -a \dot{\theta} \sin(\theta) \hat{i} + a \dot{\theta}\cos(\theta) \hat{j} + b\omega \sinh(\omega t) \hat{k}$.

The remaining parts should then follow.

Comment: Thank-you for the help, but now I'm stuck again!

I got 
dr/dt = -a(dθ/dt)sinθi + a(dθ/dt)cosj + bωsinh(ωt)k

And 
d^2r/dt^2 = [-a(dθ/dt)cosθ - a(d^2θ/dt^2)sinθ]i + [-a(dθ/dt)sinθ + a(d^2θ/dt^2)cosθ]j + bω^2cosh(ωt)k

Are these correct? Because when I try the dot product the simplest form I can get it into is 
±abωcosh(ωt)cos^2θ ±abωcosh(ωt)sin^2θ + b^2ω^2cosh(ωt)

I'm not sure how to factor that to get cos^2θ + sin^2θ out and for it all to equal zero. Sorry if this is a really silly question!

Comment: It looks like you're not taking the dot product correctly.  There should not be a $\cosh (\omega t)$ in the first or second summand in the dot product.

Recall that $(ai + bj + ck) \cdot (a'i + b'j + c'k) = aa' + bb' + cc'$.  Hopefully things cancel after that.

Answer (score 0):

You don't appear to have differentiated the expression for $r$: you should have

$$\dot r =\frac{d}{d\theta }(a\cos\theta \hat i +a\sin\theta \hat j) \dot \theta +\omega b\sinh(\omega t)\hat k$$